# Why is the first element getting removed too?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

So I am new to javascript and I tried making a todo list. This works well with adding elements. The issue is when I am removing some item, the first one gets removed too, why is it so? I know I am missing a small thing and this may be really basic but I am not able to find out what that is.

```
const App1 = () => {
    const [item, updatedItem]=useState('');
    const [Items, setItems]=useState([]);
    function inputEvent(event) {
        updatedItem(event.target.value);
    }
    const addItem = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setItems((prev) => {
            return[
                ...prev,
                item
        ]
        });
        updatedItem('');    
    }
    
    let key=0;
    return(<>
    <div className='back'>
        <div className='list'>
            <header>ToDo List</header>
                <form onSubmit={addItem}>
                    <input type='text' placeholder='Add an item' value={item} onChange={inputEvent}/>
                    <button type='submit'>+</button>
                </form>
                    <div className='items'>
                        <ol> 
                            {Items.map((val) => <li><button id={key++} onClick={(event) => {
                                setItems((Items) => {
                                    return Items.filter((val, index) => {
                                        if(index!==Number(event.target.id)){ 
                                            return index;
                                        }
                                    }
                                );
                            });
                        key=0;
                    }}>x</button>{val}</li>)}
                </ol>
            </div>    
        </div>
    </div>
</>);
```

Answer (score 3):

You return the `index` in your `filter`, expecting this to always be true, yet `0` (the index of the first element) is a [falsy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).

Try this instead:

```
return Items.filter((_val, index) => index !== Number(event.target.id));
```

---

Some unrelated code-quality notes:

1. In React, you should always set a `key` prop on each element when looping through them, rather than `id`.
2. `map` has a second argument, `index`, which it passes into the callback --- you don't have to keep track of this yourself with e.g. `key++` etc.
3. If you use `map`'s index parameter, then you can pass that directly into your filter rather than using `Number(event.target.id)`, which is not very idiomatic in React.
4. If you don't use an argument of a callback, it's a good idea to prefix it with a `_` (like I've done with `_val` here), to make it explicit that you're not using it.

Comment: It would be easy to read the combination of #1 and #2 as saying to use `index` as a key, which would be [an antipattern](https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) for an array where the contents change (such as filtering). (The OP's `key` has the same issue of course.)

Answer (score 1):

Your [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) callback should return a flag. `index` is a number. When treated as a flag, `0` is false (more [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)). Instead:

```
return Items.filter((val, index) => index !== Number(event.target.id));
```

**However**, your code is returning an array of `li` elements without setting `key` on them (see: [keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys)), which React needs in order to manage that list properly (you should be seeing a warning about it in devtools if you're using the development version of the libs, which is best in development). You can't use the mechanism you're using now for keys when doing that, it **will not work reliably** (see [this article](https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) linked by the React documentation). Instead, assign each Todo item a **unique** ID when you create it that doesn't change, and use that as the key (and as the value to look for when removing the item):

```
// Outside the component:
let lastId = 0;

// Inside the component:
const addItem = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setItems((prev) => {
        return [
            ...prev,
            {text: item, id: ++lastId}
        ];
    });
    updatedItem("");    
};

// Add a remove function:
const removeItem = ({currentTarget}) => {
    const id = +currentTarget.getAttribute("data-id"); // Get the ID, convert string to number
    setItems(items => items.filter(item => item.id !== id));
};

// When rendering:
{Items.map((item) => <li key={item.id}><button data-id={item.id} onClick={removeItem}>x</button>{item.text}</li>)}
```

In some cases it may be useful to use `useCallback` to memoize `removeItem` to avoid unnecessary rendering, but often that's overkill.

Comment: Thanks. But I didn't understand {currentTarget: {id}} thing, what does that imply and why have you used it?

Comment: And also I got this error, TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id') on the same line, where you've defined removeItem().

Comment: @TanishaSethi - That's [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Sorry about the `id` thing, I've fixed it above.

Comment: Getting this error now, TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getAttribute')

Comment: @TanishaSethi Then you're not hooking up `removeItem` the way I have it looked up in the question.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry about that. No errors now but it's removing all the items.

Comment: @TanishaSethi - The code above shouldn't do that. I suspect you've either used a string instead of a number for `id` when assigning it, or you've left off the `+` to convert the attribute value to number, so `!==` is always true (since the types don't match). In the code above, I'm using a number for `id`, and converting to number when getting the attribute value, so the types will match.

Comment: @TanishaSethi Really, though, these are just the normal things you run into when writing code, you just have to debug and resolve them.

Comment: I am sorry and it's lastId that's not getting updated